# why Asterisk SIP port (5060) is closed?

Tags: linux, installation, centos, asterisk

I defined a SIP channel on Asterisk 11.22.0 built by root @ fabio-linux on a x86_64 running Linux Centos 6 but unfortunately the port for SIP channel is closed and I'm not able to execute proxy authentication receiving 407 error.
Could someone give me an help ?
Thanks

Comment: If you get 407, this means that something wrong with authentication. Why you think that port is closed?

Comment: because some network tools say it's closed. It seems that asterisk is unable to exchange data over that port on INVITE from my SIP provvider.

Comment: Could you please name that network tools? I doubt that connection is closed. I assume your tools check connection via TCP protocol, but SIP in most cases runs over UDP.

Comment: lsof nestat nmap etc

Comment: are we discussing here TCP or UDP protocol?

Comment: UDP protocol related to SIP channel

Comment: are you sure that asterisk is running? check if there is process asterisk by following command `ps -ax | grep asterisk`

Comment: asterisk is  running

Comment: Could you please paste here out put of this 2 commands, just to be 100% sure. `ps -ax | grep asterisk` and `netstat -na`

Comment: 2714 ?        S      0:00 /bin/sh /opt/asterisk/sbin/safe_asterisk
 2716 ?        Sl     0:00 /opt/asterisk/sbin/asterisk -f -vvvg -c
 3803 ?        Ssl   0:00 asterisk vvvvvvr
 3859 pts/0  S+    0:00 grep asterisk

Comment: What about `netstat -na`?

Comment: unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     43869  /var/run/asterisk/asterisk.ctl
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     14752  /opt/asterisk/var/run/asterisk/asterisk.ctl

Comment: Please show full output of `netstat -na` or `netstat -na | grep 5060`

Comment: [root@fabio-linux fabio]# netstat -na | grep 5062
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5062                0.0.0.0:*       5062 is the new port I configured in SIP channel

Comment: ok, so if you configured 5062 and it is listening on 5062. What else you need?

Comment: it's not listening the port is CLOSED otherwise you should see LISTENING

Comment: Please patebin full output of `netstat -na`

Comment: If port in netstat, then it mean it is listening on it. Try to shut down asterisk and you will see that those ports will disappear from netstat. "LISTEN" is only for TCP protocol, for UDP you will never see there LISTEN.

Comment: [root@fabio-linux fabio]# netstat -anp | grep  5062
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5062                0.0.0.0:*                               3803/asterisk

Comment: please see my answer

Answer (score 1):

On Centos you need to configure SELinux.

To turn it off: `sed -i s/SELINUX=enforcing/SELINUX=disabled/g /etc/selinux/config`

then `reboot`

That should help:

http://blogs.digium.com/2012/11/05/how-to-install-asterisk-11-on-centos-6/

http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/installing_base_configuration.html

Comment: Could you post provider connection section from sip.conf?

Comment: [CheapVoIP] 
type=peer 
defaultuser=xxx@sip.cheapnet.it 
secret=********** 
fromuser=xxx 
fromdomain=sip.cheapnet.it 
host=sip.cheapnet.it 
outboundproxy=sip.cheapnet.it 
insecure = invite,port 
realm=sip.cheapnet.it 
nat=yes 
qualify=yes 
regseconds=60 
disallow=all 
allow=alaw 
allow=ulaw 
allow=g729

Comment: And register information? Maybe this could help: http://nazarenolatella.myblog.it/2014/12/09/configurarazione-asterisk-cheapvoip-it/ . Can you enable sip debug on CheapVoIP and dump connection states with that provider?